# Decode Form Urlencoded UTF8 in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-parsing

**Edit** I'd misunderstood what was happening here.. there is a POST send, then receive back a result, then the URL string which I'm seeing here is part of the the query string... so I can't decode what this really is, as it is encoded by the payment gateway people and not me.

I'd like to decode a URL string

Here is the code:

```
private string SubmitXml(string InputXml)
    {
        string result = InputXml.ToString();

        HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_WebServiceUrl);
        webReq.Method = "POST";

        byte[] reqBytes;

        reqBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InputXml);
        webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webReq.ContentLength = reqBytes.Length;
        webReq.Timeout = 5000;
        Stream requestStream = webReq.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(reqBytes, 0, reqBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
```

Here is the InputXml:

```
 - <GenerateRequest>
  <PxPayUserId>KoruCareCHCH_Dev</PxPayUserId> 
  <PxPayKey>47d99ccdcae54816ecd78c9a80f8878c466a7ed829480e59d421cc4c456cbd93</PxPayKey> 
  <AmountInput>345.00</AmountInput> 
  <BillingId /> 
  <CurrencyInput>NZD</CurrencyInput> 
  <DpsBillingId /> 
  <DpsTxnRef /> 
  <EmailAddress /> 
  <EnableAddBillCard /> 
  <MerchantReference>43</MerchantReference> 
  <TxnData1 /> 
  <TxnData2 /> 
  <TxnData3 /> 
  <TxnType>Purchase</TxnType> 
  <TxnId>43</TxnId> 
  <UrlFail>http://localhost:1527/Auction/PurchaseTickets.aspx</UrlFail> 
  <UrlSuccess>http://localhost:1527/Auction/PurchaseTickets.aspx</UrlSuccess> 
  <Opt /> 
  </GenerateRequest>
```

Here is the URL

https://sec2.paymentexpress.com/pxpay/pxpay.aspx?userid=KoruCareCHCH_Dev&request=v5lK0D7j3qnGqQVnj3WThhuS5PoWwKhdLUXfnL1hiSzYzxzkKVtTbLKC49e0qerYoTAofoBXfkWHjJdtOEV1MrnEBZ3p9b-G5fTsS-sLqc76RhHOb8HTxtwe0EQ1kz1iCf2ExIgKRod-FPQTKf6XoTLLlQ4jhcrO7yQczrq1Hft5pB98LMJCdBX0FDnA5NV0ZGApR0NaCMy-xbpsVSsyTbSdmp03aiHpGXI4up2RxrBFhbiEOZKtpKkjUpqJ90UuoXmFwqTC5Pj0g1mx3VRV2ee358Tnu1_kuEID_RaP8sZNTVlAMY5-8qjB-u0dgM4ya8Faxxyw5AhyE=

**Problem:** How do I decode the URL request=blahblah    back into XML

I'm doing this to try and prove what is contained in the URL string (it should be just like the XML above!)

Comment: the title of your question should probably be edited; it is misleading.

Comment: done thanks pierre - is this a better title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't have any luck decoding it so the URL might be wrong, but I used this code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(...);
NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
string value = query["request"].Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
Debug.WriteLine(Convert.FromBase64String(value));
```

---

EDIT: In their docs they say it's encrypted.

Comment: Thanks JD - even though they say its encrypted I can't see in the code where it does it.  All I'm trying to do is go from the cleartext InputXml to the request part of the URL and back again.. hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex, something like

```
var match = new Regex("request=(?<key>[^&]+)").Match(url);
```

and capture the request value in the named group.  From there, hopefully you'd be able to decrypt the captured value.

No guarantees that the above regex is correct - I haven't tested it.  It should at least point you in the right direction!

Comment: Hi Ben.. many thanks.. am fine getting the request out of the URL.. its decoding what is in the request string that has me scratching my head!